# pydub "ModuleNotFoundError" when using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, pydub

I am trying to convert a .py file to .exe using pyinstaller. When I try to run the executable the following error is shown :
[image: error]

My current pyinstaller command is the following:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console  --hidden-import "pydub" --add-data "C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/customtkinter;customtkinter/"  "C:/Users/me/PycharmProjects/TestProj/main.py"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already pip installed pydub and added pydub to the hidden imports I tried to delete every file in my Virtual Environment that I didn't need. Deleting all Pycharm related files and deleting the old build/dist folder alongside the .spec file seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it with pip .

```
pip3 install pydub
```

Maybe you have multiple python versions

Comment: Already did that. pip show pydub shows me version 0.25.1

Comment: refer to this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57227191/pyinstaller-hidden-import-not-found